# How to compute e(g1^x,g1^x) with golang.org/x/crypto/bn256?

Tags: go, cryptography

The golang package [bn256](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/bn256) can do this: e(g_1^x,g_2^y), but I want to compute e(g_1^x,g_1^y).

Is there any way to transfer a point on g1 to g2?

Comment: I don't think this optimal Ate pairing provides an efficient hash function from G1 to G2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bn256 does not let you do symmetric pairing with pair(G1,G2).

One way to go about it is to raise the destination group element to the desired exponent.

Answer (score 0):

I use [this](https://github.com/Nik-U/pbc) insteadly.

It is a golang wrapper around pbc library.